# FreeNX(nomachine) unable to connect after cloning of a working ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, nomachine-nx

I have previously setup a EC2 instance on Ubuntu 10.04 and setup the necessary binaries to allow ssh and more importantly FreeNX(no machine) to work on my MacOS-10.6 machine.

As this was done on a micro instance, i was keen to try it on small instance today so i created a AMI image from the aws management console(browser) and launch a new small instance using the image with the exact same keypair and security setting.

Expecting the instance to work exactly the same(except much faster) i tried to connect to it using SSH and FreeNX again.

Result:

- SSH is working fine and my env look exactly the same.
- NX is unable to connect.

it complain username/password is incorrect.

I wonder why this is happen since i did an exact clone of the EC2 instance and i can connect fine using NX with the previous instance?

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message you are seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and after a lot of searching fixed it. It seems freenx lost the usernames and passwords. I fixed it by doing the following:

log in with putty as ubuntu user then

```
cd /etc/nxserver
sudo vim node.conf
set ENABLE_PASSDB_AUTHENTICATION="1" and save the file
```

then

```
sudo nxserver --adduser xxxxxx
sudo nxserver --passwd yyyyyy
sudo nxserver --restart
```

after that I was able to log in using nomachine with the username and password I just set.